# Cisco vWLC sha2 certificates not supported bug?

Tags: cisco, virtual-machines, wifi, certificate

I currently have an app running with a Cisco virtual Wireless Lan Controller, all works fine except we get some error messages regarding SHA1 certificates, when I'm looking for SHA2 support the cisco release notes tell me that SHA2 certificates are not supported, even in the latest 8.2.100.0 release.  Can anyone confirm this, or better yet does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: That's something you are going to need to ask Cisco about. Only Cisco can fix it, and if it is in the release notes for that version, you are stuck until Cisco supports it. Cisco is pretty good about answering you questions and will tell you if it is known in which future version support for it will be.

Comment: This should be asked in Cisco TAC, not here.